# Open Debugger react-native 0.70

Tags: react-native, flipper

I want to open debugger using hermes but log error  `Browser exited with error:, Error: invalid url, missing http/https protocol` how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

To debug Hermes you can use Flipper or you can follow this instruction https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes#debugging-js-on-hermes-using-google-chromes-devtools

Comment: It not working for me

Comment: @phuocantd have you read this advice https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34615#issuecomment-1245364472
you need to instal Flipper and try with Flipper

Comment: It working on react native v0.67, v0.68 but not working on react native v0.70